# Facebook requests redirecting to Play Store (not to the actual app, when it's already installed)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have an android app, and I'm trying to use Facebook Deep linking.
I sent a request to another facebook user (who already has the app installed), but it always redirects him to the Play Store app page, instead of sending him to the actual app.

Can anybody help me ? I'm following this guide but it's not so helpful:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial?locale=es_LA#requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually had a bad configuration on Facebook App settings. Missing namespace in class name.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests

Comment: the link is broken, but you can still find it using [way back machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140929051438/https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests). That took me a full evening to figure out. Fortunately the facebook docs are very detailed and up to date. So basically the `Class Name` field in the facebook developers console should contain the full class name (ex: `com.domain.appname.MainActivity`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mobile site url as a platform on facebook app settings. This would enable redirection to google play store. This might be an issue in facebook.
Also check this: http://www.wenda.io/questions/1875350/facebook-android-sdk-app-request-not-redirects-to-google-play-store.html

Comment: I already have that. The thing is, I need to redirect TO THE APP, because the user already has it installed.. but it keeps sending the user to the play store

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, although I already had the package correctly in the class name I also had to switch on the 'Single Sign On' option before it would open the installed app instead of opening Play Store.

[image: Android 'Single Sign On' option in Facebook settings]